# overriden onPrepared not being called automatically

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

The following is the service class of my music player, the implemented onPrepared() method is never called, so I have to use setOnPreparedListener to get the things done.
I want to execute it from the unimplemented section.

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    //media player 
    private MediaPlayer player;
    //song list
    private ArrayList<Song> songs;
    //current position
    private int songPosn;
    private String songTitle="";
    private static final int NOTIFY_ID=1;
    private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return musicBind;
    }

    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        //initialize position
        songPosn = 0;
        //create player
        player = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    //this is never being called and instead of this the one in setOnPreparedListener is called
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //start music 
        mp.start();

        Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendInt)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play)
        .setTicker(songTitle)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentText("Playing")
        .setContentText(songTitle);
        Notification not = builder.build();
        startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, not);
    }

    public void initMusicPlayer(){
        //set player properties
        player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    public void setSong(int songIndex){
        songPosn=songIndex;
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<Song> theSongs){
        songs = theSongs;
    }

    public void playSong(){
        //play a cool song
        player.reset();
        //get song

        Song playSong = songs.get(songPosn);
        songTitle = playSong.getTitle();
        //get ID
        long currSong = playSong.getId();
        //set path to sdcard or squaremash server
        Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, currSong);
        try {
            player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Music service","Error: setting data source",e);  }
        player.prepareAsync();
        //this one is called, If I remove this, the above onPrepared method isnt called
        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.start(); 
            }
        });
    }

    public void go(){
        player.start();
    }
    //previous song
    public void playPrev() {
        songPosn--;
        if(songPosn<0)
            songPosn=songs.size()-1;
        playSong();
    }
    //next song
    public void playNext() {
        songPosn++;
        if(songPosn>=songs.size())
            songPosn=0;
        playSong();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set the correct OnPreparedListener.

In `onCreate()` when you create the player, you should set the listener there:

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setOnPreparedListener(this)
```

And remove the other one, otherwise it'll override the first.

---

When you implement an interface, it's just setting a contract on the class: "this class *has* these particular methods, feel free to call them". `MediaPlayer` needs to know *which* `OnPreparedListener` to use (`MediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener`) otherwise it won't do anything.

Comment: onPreparedListener works, but normally as I have implemented the interface so the method onPrepared should be called, which is not working, thats why I have added onPreparedListener

Comment: Did you set the listener (`this`) on the player?

Comment: yes I just did and added all my code from onPreparedListener to ""public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)..

Answer (score 3):

This is not how Java works.

You're extending a `Service` object. There is nothing in that object's lifecycle that triggeres a call to `onPrepared()`. What triggers that call is your `player` member:

```
private MediaPlayer player;
```

And for that to happen, i.e. for `player` to trigger a call to `onPrepared()`, you need to point it to an object implementing `onPrepared()`. This object is your `MusicService` object, thus you need to call:

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
```

Comment: @AdityaVerma if you like the answer please mark it as a solution.